# How to make sure one class can only be instantiated with an object of another one, without exposing internals?

Tags: kotlin

Let's say we have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar`.
A `Bar` should only be constructible from a `Foo` object.

Here are my current attempts with the reason why I don't consider them to be proper solutions:

---

Attempt 1:

```
class Foo {
    var data: Int = 0 // meh: This implementation detail should not be exposed to the public.
    fun add(x: Int) {
        data += x
    }
}

class Bar(foo: Foo) {
    private var data: Int = 2 * foo.data
    fun show() = println(data + 10)
}

fun main() {
    val myFoo = Foo()
    myFoo.add(3)
    myFoo.add(4)
    val myBar = Bar(myFoo)
    myBar.show()
}
```

Problem: `Foo::data` should not be visible from the outside.

---

Attempt 2:

```
class Foo {
    private var data: Int = 0
    fun add(x: Int) {
        data += x
    }

    fun makeBar() = Bar(2 * data)
}

class Bar(private val data: Int) { // meh: Bar should only be instantiated from a Foo.
    fun show() = println(data + 10)
}

fun main() {
    val myFoo = Foo()
    myFoo.add(3)
    myFoo.add(4)
    val myBar = myFoo.makeBar()
    myBar.show()
}
```

Problem: Everybody can create a `Bar` now, even without having a `Foo` at hand.

---

Coming from C++ my first idea to solve this, would be to make the constructor of `Bar` private, but let only `Foo` access it by declaring it to be a [`friend`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) class. Is something similar possible in Kotlin, or is there another (better) solution?

Comment: I think you can with creating Foo Bar classes in different module and make Foo::data internal.. So that it's only visible on that module .. For rest of the modules it's not accessible.

Comment: Make Bar an inner class of Foo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your use case you are probably looking for an [inner class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#inner-classes) then. Here is a solution derived from your first attempt using an inner class `Bar`:

```
class Foo {
    private var data = 0 // private as you do not want to make it publicly available
    fun add(x: Int) {
        data += x
    }

    inner class Bar {
        private var data = 2 * this@Foo.data // access the outer foo directly... no need to hold it in the constructor
        fun show() = println(data + 10)
    }
}    

fun main() {
    val myFoo = Foo()
    myFoo.add(3)
    myFoo.add(4)
    // val myBar = Foo.Bar() // this does not compile... you need a foo to build a bar...
    val myBar = myFoo.Bar() // this works...
    myBar.show()
    // myBar.data // this wouldn't compile as it's not accessible
}
```

As you said, you prefer a top level class. Depending on how secure you want `Foo.data` to be, you may also be interested in the following setup:

```
class Foo {
    private var data = 0
    fun add(x: Int) {
        data += x
    }
    fun Bar.getFooData() = data
}

class Bar(foo: Foo) {
    private var data = 2 * with(foo) { getFooData() }
    fun show() = println(data + 10)
}
```

So you can only access Foo's data when you have both, a `Bar` and a `Foo` available, the latter as receiver. That however also means, that you can access `Foo.data` from outside, if both objects are available to you, e.g. the following will succeed also in `main`:

```
with (myFoo) {
  myBar.getFooData()
}
```

So: making `data` unaccessible from outside (ignoring reflection), nested or inner class is your friend. Making it harder to access it (or: forcing some conditions to be true, before using it), the extension function approach with appropriate receiver might be your friend.

Comment: Thanks. Another solution based on a similar idea looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/02699fe4c353418ba63e170668b0b59d). I'd prefer the class to be a top-level one, but I guess this is the best we can get.

Comment: @TobiasHermann ok. in this particular case however I think you are better of just using the inner class. would it be ok for you, if the `Foo.data` would only be accessible by an instance of `bar`? If so, you may also want to play around with extension functions within `Foo`, e.g. `fun Bar.getData() = data` which basically makes it visible to any instance of `Bar`... I will update the answer to show what I mean...

Comment: Thanks again. This time for your edit. :) I think I prefer the inner/nested class version.

Comment: For completeness, it's also possible to [make `Foo` the inner class](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/0680129fa2bb55bdab901e82964b294d). But this moves the logic of building the `Bar` into `Foo`. So I like your version (`Bar` inside `Foo`) better.